# Get all the related object based on the models filter query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Trying to get all the list of loan along with the related its addresses linked to that particular loan.

Models:

```
class LoanDetail(models.Model):
    job_no = models.AutoField('Job No', primary_key=True)
    loan_account_no = models.CharField('Loan account No', blank=True, max_length=128)
    job_status = models.IntegerField('Job Status', choices=JOB_STATUS, default=1, db_index=True)
    applicant_type = models.IntegerField('Applicant type', choices=APPLICANT_TYPE, default=1, db_index=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField('Customer Name', max_length=128)

class LoanUserAddress(models.Model):
    loan = models.ForeignKey(LoanDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="loanuser")
    address_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressType)
    house_name = models.CharField('House/Flat/Name', max_length=128)
    street = models.CharField('Street', max_length=128)
    area = models.CharField('Area/Location', max_length=128)
```

views:

```
class SearchLoan(APIView, ResponseViewMixin):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        loan = kwargs['loan'];
        address = LoanDetail.objects.filter(loan_account_no__in=[loan])
```

This is returning only the loan details how can I get all the Address along with the loandetails.

I would like the response to be like

`{'loan_account_no': '12412412421', 'customer_name': 'Ravi' , address: [
{'id': 1, 'house_name': 'Some aadress'},
{'id': 2, 'house_name': 'Some aadress 2'},
{'id': 3, 'house_name': 'Some aadress 3'}] }`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the addresses for a set of loads

```
addresses = LoanUserAddress.objects.filter(loan__loan_account_no__in=[loan])
```

If you want a list of loans with the adresses, get the list of loans like you did

```
loans = LoanDetail.objects.filter(loan_account_no__in=[loan])
```

and for each items in the queryset you can access the attribute `loanuser` that will be the list of addresses for this loan. where `loanuser` is the `related_name` of the ForeignKey field.

```
for loan_item in loans.all():
    print(loan_item.loanuser)
```

Comment: There's no point using an `in` query with a list of one item.